# Vim scroll window like in less pager (with single key)?

Tags: vim-windows, scrolling

I really like how the less pager uses <kbd>w</kbd> to scroll up and <kbd>z</kbd> to scroll down since they are single keys, in vim I have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to get the same effect. Having to hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is a bit of a nuisance.

Of course I could just remap the scroll keys, but that might break plugins, generate bad karma, etc, etc...

Is there a single key shortcut to move down by a screen already?
Your suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not a member of the clan of arrow keys haters, and if your distribution provider didn't screw up your `termcap` / `terminfo` database, the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> keys should work just fine.  And so would <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>, and even the arrow keys, both in insert, normal, select, visual, and Ex modes (and whatever else Vim has in store that I can't remember just now).

On the other hand, if you *are* a member of said clan, you'll have to stop listening to the filthy arrow keys propaganda and just get used to the One True Way of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>.

Comment: Just for completeness. I decided to go with this in my vimrc: `nnoremap <Up> 10k` and `nnoremap <Down> 10j` seem to work nicely.

Comment: IMHO, you should have mapped those keys to ctrl-u and and cltr-d, respectively. Then you could `set scroll=10` to have a similar behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the "single key" shortcuts are used for the more important and useful **editing** operations. Pagers don't have this problem, since they are by definition viewers, so they have all single keys available for buffer presentation.

But, in read-only Vim buffers (e.g. when reading a help topic), it may make sense to locally re-assign some of keys. If you place the following lines in your `.vimrc`, you will remap `d`, `u` and `q` in read-only buffers to scroll down a page, scroll up a page or quit, respectively:

```
augroup vimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * call s:check_readonly()
augroup END

function! s:check_readonly()
    if &readonly
        nnoremap <buffer> d <PageDown>
        nnoremap <buffer> u <PageUp>
        nnoremap <buffer> q :q<cr>
    endif
endfunction
```

Reference: [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) and vim's help system.